# MySql is not starting xampp on ubuntu

Tags: 11.10, mysql, xampp

I have recently migrated to ubuntu and I have intalled Xampp for Ubuntu .. lampp
as per the instructions mentioned on xampp website, i have installed the lampp

[lampp Installation](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-linux.html#377)

And it was starting good.. when i changed the `/opt/lampp` permission mode to `777` by using from `Terminal` as `chmod 777 /opt/lamp`.

After this when i start the lampp, it gives the below error in images in `Terminal` as well as `web page error`

`Terminal Error` Image

[image]

`web page error` when i typed `localhost/phpmyadmin` it gives below error

[image]

So,
how can i revert the changes or 
how can i start the mysql server service

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you did a `chmod 777` please do a

```
chmod 775 /opt/lamp
```

Regarding the error during startup...

MySQL complains about `my.cnf` being world-writeable. MySQL does not use the config file if you change `/opt/lamp/etc/my.cnf` to **7. To fix that specific problem do a...

```
chmod 644 /opt/lampp/etc/my.cnf
```

and MySQL will use it again.

Regarding permissions...

For directories 775 (or even 755) is more than enough and for files 664 (or even 644) is more than enough. Using 777 will let people from the whole world access your files where they can alter and execute those files.

And a final note...

I see XAMPP being mentioned in your image. I would advice not to use an external LAMP setup. There is a perfectly working LAMP version in Ubuntu Software Center that is custom made to work with Ubuntu.

Comment: I didnt found any lamp in ubuntu software center..

Comment: @Rafee https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Tasksel In contradiction to the article you nowadays need to install `tasksel` before you can install lamp.