# Ubuntu xampp, mysql wont start at all

Tags: 14.04, permissions, mysql, xampp

After changing whatever I saw and I found, unfortunately no success.

When I installed xampp it ran successfully and both apache and mysql started. But surprisingly after restart below errors begin to occur.

When I run XAMPP control-panel on ubuntu 14.04, apache2 start correctly but mysql cant start as shown:
[image: Click on start and wait to see running status]
But after some seconds:
[image]

Also When I run phpmyadmin, below errors shown:

```
--First Error--

#2002 - Connection refused
The server is not responding (or the local server's socket is not correctly configured). 

--Second Error--

Connection for controluser as defined in your configuration failed.
```

Port 3306 is free, permission of `config.inc.php` is `755`, permission of whole `/opt` is `777`, also change host entry in `config.inc.php` from `localhost` to `127.0.0.1`... nothing changed.

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Anything in your `/var/log/mysql/error.log`? And could you start XAMMP from the command line? Did you try this solution? http://askubuntu.com/a/97091/448431

Comment: Have you, by any chance, installed another web server? I once had Apache dying because Nginx wasn't letting go of port 80.

Comment: @dotslash I'm sure that there is no any web service within lampp apache. Also my apache start without any problem. Also I remove ubuntu built in mysql and no difference achieved. As I said after install it works properly but after system reboot it'll be messed up.

Answer (score 0):

If your system restart forcefully then pid file may be generated cant start at startup so you need to remove it once

If you are using Xampp on ubuntu then follow below steps:

goto `/opt/lampp/logs/`

then run below command

```
sudo rm -rf httpd.pid
```

then goto `/opt/var/mysql/`

then run below command

```
sudo rm -rf system hostname.err
```

and restart service

```
sudo /opt/lampp/lampp restart
```

That's it